# The testing process for pulpit position candidates

Tags: test

What was/is the name of the process of testing out a candidate for the position of pulpit rav (presumably a Yiddish term)?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are referring to is called a "probeh". See here for more details:

[Where does "probeh" come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53337/16354)